# Retrieving data from DataModel (Power Pivot) within VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, powerpivot, cube

first of all, apologies. I am a relatively new VBA user, and I am a bit lost in the search for the answer to the question below.

I am creating a UserForm which will include some ComboBox to get user's input to query data.
I would like the possible values of these ComboBoxes to be "pulled" from the DataModel of the workbook, where I loaded (as Connection Only) the Excel file containing the possible options.
Such excel is organized by columns (one column per ComboBox I'll need to use), where each row is a possible value for the comboBox.

I would strongly prefer to load the file as connection only (rather than creating a PivotTable in one of the Workbook sheets).

I believe that, if I were able to "extract" from the columns in the DataModel the various values in each column, I could use the Add.Item method of the ComboBox.

The issue I am having: I cannot retrieve the values of the columns in the Power Pivot Data Model.

The data in the Power Pivot is organized as such:

Table name: src_FieldOptions
Column1: Door Options (possible values in rows: Electric, Pneumatic, Manual)
Column2: Finishing (Painted, Glossy, Matte)

I tried to use the code using the DataModel Object (see below), but I can't find a way to retrieve the column values (for each row), even if I am able to identify the columns.

Any help you can give?
Thanks a lot

```vb
Sub Find_Values()

    Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
   
    Dim model_Table As modelTable
    Dim model_Column As ModelTableColumn

    ' Set the connection to the Power Pivot Data Model
    Set conn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - src_FieldOptions")
    
    For Each model_Table In conn.ModelTables
       Debug.Print "Table Name: " & model_Table.Name. '<--this is working as expected
       For Each model_Column In model_Table.ModelTableColumns
           Debug.Print "Column Header: " & model_Column.Name & "; " & model_Column.DataType '<-- working as expected

        ' QUESTION FOR YOU ALL: what code should I use here to retrieve the values in the rows of the Data model? 

        Next model_Column
    Next model_Table
       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I couldn't locate any property of `ModelTable` object for retrieving data in `Object Browser`.
- There is a walkaround solution to retrieve data with data model `ADOConnection`.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ModelConnection.ADOConnection property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.modelconnection.adoconnection?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm922075)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Find_Value_Demo()
    Dim oConn As WorkbookConnection, oRS As Object ' Recordset
    Dim oCnn As Object, sTabName As String
    ' Set the connection to the Power Pivot Data Model
    Set oConn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - src_FieldOptions")
    ' Set oConn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Table1") ' for testing
    sTabName = oConn.ModelTables(1).Name ' Assumes there is only a table
    Set oCnn = ThisWorkbook.Model.DataModelConnection.ModelConnection.ADOConnection
    Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    oRS.Open "SELECT * From $" & sTabName & ".$" & sTabName, oCnn
    ' modify as need, to manipulate the data
    Dim i As Long, c As Long
    Sheets.Add
    For i = 1 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1
        Cells(1, i).Value = oRS.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i
    oRS.MoveFirst
    i = 2
    Do While Not oRS.EOF
        For c = 1 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1
            Cells(i, c) = oRS.Fields(c - 1)
        Next
        i = i + 1
        oRS.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update:

> Question: I don't understand the reason for referencing twice the sTabName (both with "$" and with ".$"

- It's a MSOLAP sql. The syntax is different with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

```
?oCnn
Provider=MSOLAP.8;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Microsoft_SQLServer_AnalysisServices;Data Source=$Embedded$;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Subqueries=0;Optimize Response=7;Update Isolation Level=2
```

- A query to extract recordes with non-blank `name`

```
 sSql = "EVALUATE FILTER('Table1', NOT ISBLANK([name]))"
```

- Another sql option to extract all rows

```
sSql = "EVALUATE 'Table1'"
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked like a charm!  Could you also help me understand how the SELECT query should be written if I wanted to exclude the NULL values on a specific column?                                                       
oRS.Open "SELECT " & sColName & " From $" & sTabName & ".$" & sTabName & "  WHERE " & sColName & " IS NOT NULL", oCnn   always gives me a runtime error (Method Open doesn't work).   I can't understans why (probably I don't understand the reason for referencing twice the sTabName (both with "$" and with ".$").  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide...

Comment: May I ask for another clarification for the use of EVALUATE? The simplest form of EVALUATE works for me ( sSQL = "EVALUATE " & sTabName), followed by oRS.Open sSQL, oCnn.    Howeve, as I go into more complex EVALUATE options, the oRS.Open instruction always gives me runtime error.
    
sSQL = "EVALUATE SELECTCOLUMNS (" & _
       sTabName & ", " & _
        sTabName & "[Cantiere], " & _
        sTabName & "[Imbarcazione]" & _
        ")".     Where "Cantiere" and "Imbarcazione" are the headers of the columns I want to extract. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: Thanks! Will do. Very new to StackOverflow - thanks for guiding me!